# Any fix for chrome and it's timeupdate event bug on audio/video tags?

Tags: audio, google-chrome

Just stumbled upon a huge bug in Chrome (looks like it is fixed in coming Chrome 5): http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=25185, basically it stops throwing timeupdate events after two or three seconds of playing, hence no way to update player interface.

Is there any established javascript level fix for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Patch has landed in Chromium.

It sucks anyway.